# How to use split() and read the first character of a string of a file?

Tags: java, arrays, file, polymorphism

For example, I want to split the commas of this file and read the first character of each line. Based on the first character `(#,*,@)`, I want to create an object using the data after each character(`Steve Davis 2000`).

```
4     
#Steve,Davis,2000
*John,Kanet,800,7000,0.10
@Thomas,Hill,20,50
*Lisa,Green,800,6000,0.10
```

The 4 is used as a size for my array

So far this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class PayRoll3{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

    Scanner input=new Scanner(new File(args[0]));  
    int size=input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();

    Employee[] employees = new Employee[size];
    int index = 0;

    while(input.hasNext()){
        String tmp= input.next();
        String[] commas = tmp.split(",");

        if(tmp.substring(0,1).equals("#")){
        employees[index++]=new Manager2(input.next(), input.next(), input.nextDouble() );
        }
        else if(tmp.substring(0,1).equals("*")){
        employees[index++]=new CommissionEmployee2(input.next(), input.next(), input.nextDouble(), input.nextDouble(), input.nextDouble());
        }
        else if(tmp.substring(0,1).equals("@")){
                employees[index++]=new HourlyWorker2(input.next(), input.next(), input.nextDouble(), input.nextDouble()); 
        }
         }

      input.close();

      for ( Employee currentEmployee : employees ){
          System.out.println( currentEmployee );
          }               
}
```

When i run the code i get

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException 
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source) 
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source) 
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source) 
 at PayRoll3.main(PayRoll3.java:19)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a pretty good start for an excellent question - you have a description of the problem, and you also show your code that tries to solve it. One thing that is missing is a description of what happens when you run your code. Click [edit], and add this description at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Could you paste the stack trace so that we could locate error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `charAt()` instead to get first character of a String to decide which object you want to create.

Use `nextLine()` instead of `next()` to get the whole line, then use `split` method to split that whole line by comma.

Use `substring(1)` to get rid of the first character. This will assume that you want the whole string character by character starting from the second index (which is 1) to the end of the string which gives you eventually the string you want with out the first character of it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class PayRoll3{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

    Scanner input=new Scanner(new File(args[0]));  
    int size=input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();

    Employee[] employees = new Employee[size];
    int index = 0;

    while(input.hasNext()){
        String tmp= input.nextLine();
        String[] commas = tmp.split(",");

        if(commas[0].charAt(0) == '#'){
            employes[index++] = new Manager2(commas[0].substring(1), commas[1], Double.parseDouble(commas[2]));
        }
        else if (commas[0].charAt(0) == '*'){
            employes[index++] = new ComissionEmployee2(commas[0].substring(1), commas[1], Double.parseDouble(commas[2]), Double.parseDouble(commas[3]), Double.parseDouble(commas[4]));
        }
        else if (commas[0].charAt(0) == '@'){
        employes[index++] = new HourlyWorkey2(commas[0].substring(1), commas[1], Double.parseDouble(commas[2]), Double.parseDouble(commas[3]));
        }

    }

    input.close();

    for (Employee currentEmployee : employees ){
        System.out.println( currentEmployee );
    }
```

Comment: This has a slight problem. `commas[0]` will still contain the constructor character (`#`, `*` or `@`). I assume that the employee names' aren't actually `#John` or `#Mark` - as cool as it would be to have a hashtag first name.

Comment: I've made the changes.

Comment: `str.substring(1)` is equivalent to `str.substring(1, str.length())`. But besides that, awesome.

Comment: I'm still getting an error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 
     at PayRoll3.main(PayRoll3.java:19)

Comment: Can you try it now ? In the first if statement I've written `Double.parseDouble(commas[3])` which is wrong because the next index is **2** , so I've edited that piece like this `Double.parseDouble(commas[2])`.